# Codeigniter - Hide controller name. Just show parameter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to hide my controller name from being shows in the URL. Currently this is the URL www.example.xyz/page/information-technology-and-human

my route file is like this:

```
$route['page/(:any)'] = "frontend/$1";
$route['login'] = "frontend/login";
```

I want to remove the "page" in the URL. So it should be like this:

```
www.example.xyz/information-technology-and-human
```

How to do this. Please help me. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this, as the last route defined in the `routes.php` file. It's important to define this wildcard route as the last route.

```
$route['(:any)'] = "frontend/$1";
```

Comment: `$route['/(:any)'] = "frontend/$1";`

By doing this all other routes will be redirected to `frontend/$1`

Comment: Not if he puts it last in the file

Comment: No need to say thank you. On Stack Overflow, you say thank you be accepting the answer and/or voting it up.

Comment: Yes. It's work. But on my case i have to remove "/" and it's look like this $route['(:any)'] = "frontend/$1";

Comment: Yes, that is fine. If this answer worked for you, you may accept it and upvote it.

Answer (score -2):

You can define custom routes in config routes may be something like this

```
$route['contact'] = 'controller_name/contact';
```

then you can access it like

```
http://your-domain/contact
```